# How do I stop a specific function by using a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have user sign up view and a dismiss button that dismisses the view. For the username textfield I used the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method to make a server request to check if that username is available or not, and send an alert if it isn't. The issue is, if I insert a username that is already taken and I dismiss the view as if i didn't want to sign up anymore, that alert still shows on another view. How do I implement some code in the dismiss button that negates the `textFieldShouldEndEditing` function?

here is my `textFieldShouldEndEditing` code:

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        var isTaken: Bool = false

        if textField == usernameTxt { var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0){
                    isTaken = true
                    let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "username \(textField.text) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "OK")

                } else {
                    println("Username is available. ")
                }
            } else {
                println("error")
            }
          }
        }
        return true
    }
```

regardless if the view is dismissed, the alert still shows, how do i get it to stop if the view is no longer present?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app delegate

add a variable

```
var signUpOn = false
```

Next, In your sign up view controller add these methods to change the singUpOn variable when you get into and out.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).signUpOn = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).signUpOn = false
}
```

Then in your query's completion block check the flag and show the alert.

```
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    var isTaken: Bool = false

    if textField == usernameTxt {

        var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: usernameTxt.text)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                if (objects!.count > 0){
                    isTaken = true

                    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).signUpOn
                    {
                        let myAlert = SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "username \(textField.text) is already taken", closeButtonTitle: "OK")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("Username is available. ")
                }
            } else {
                println("error")
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

I don't know if the cancel method is called in a proper way. If it is called properly and didn't cancel the block then maybe it is not the way we cancel the query. I'm not quite familiar with the PFQuery.

Comment: well the dismiss button never programmatically dismissed the view, it was just segued back to another view when selected

Comment: im also getting an error from the `query.cancel()` line stating: atal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Then you have to use use the method prepareForSegue()

Comment: can't i just leave the storyboard segue and just add the method to button?

Comment: You can keep the segue and don't need to use the method. Check the above answer and let me know if it is working.

Comment: Don't forget to replace the segue identifier. Good luck :)

Comment: this didn't work, the alert still came through to the next view :(

Comment: Please make sure that the cancel() method is being called when you fire up the segue. Set a break point and check if the method is being called.

Comment: so as i step through, the `if query != nil` statement is returning `query = (PFQuery!) nil`

Comment: why is that? and wouldn't that be the reason cancel isn't being called

Comment: and its stepping right over the cancel call, which means it isn't being called

Comment: Did you set the identifier of the segue and changed the YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFIER string for the same as the segue's identifier? Just for check.

Comment: i even changed the `if query != nil` to `if query == nil` and set a breakpoint, it recognized the cancel call this time, but still, the alert showed

Comment: Would you check my answer again? :) If you have your custom AppDelegate class then change the name to it.